# Best way to link a list of foreign keys to a list of entities in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In my application, attachements are added to the database before the main entity is created. The attachements are uploaded while the user is filling in the form. The ids of the attachements are returned to the browser client. Then, when the entity is created, a json object is sent of the following form (C# representation):

```
public class EntityModel {
   // some properties
   //...
   ICollection<int> AttachementIds { get;set; }
}
```

Now I would like to save these id's in an Entity Framework-like, and efficient way. Ideally there would be some Entity Framework feature like this.

```
public class Entity {
    public ICollection<Attachement> Attachements;
    public ICollection<int> AttachementsIds;
}
```

Where I'd just have to do:

```
Entity entity = Mapper.Map<Entity>(entityModel);
dbContext.Entities.Add(entity);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

And then can query like this:

```
List<Attachement> attachements = dbContext.Entities.Find(1).Attachements.ToList();
```

How to do something similar efficiently, if possible, keeping the attachements in the database?

Thanks

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvote? Is there an easy way to do this without fetching the attachements out of the database or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since you have the FKs no need to fetch. Assuming your Attachement has an Id property, don't add the collection of int IDs to the entity model(Entity). Now you can save like this (there are other ways as well):

```
var entity = Mapper.Map<Entity>(entityModel);  //parent properties
foreach (var id in  AttachementsIds)
{
    entity.Attachements.Add(new Attachement { Id = id });
}
dbContext.Entities.Add(entity);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Need to adjust your query as Find() won't bring back the children (or work with ToList):

```
var attachement = dbContext.Entities
                           .Include(e => e.Attachements)
                           .First(e => e.Id == 1);
```

Or if you want a list:

```
var attachements = dbContext.Entities
                            .Include(e => e.Attachements)
                            .ToList();
```